# mfc autosuggest textbox (like in Windows Start->Run dialog)

Tags: c++, mfc

In Windows XP if you click Start, Run (or Windows-key + R) you get a little dialog for running things directly. If you start typing, a resizable scroll-list pops up underneath the edit-box.

I want something similar, so when a user is typing in a name to an edit-box, a list will suddenly appear if suggestions can be made. But I don't know if I need to write it all myself, or can use some existing controls/code from somewhere.

Comment: The keyword here is "autocomplete".

Comment: This is called AutoSuggest ... AutoComplete fills out the edit box for you ... this is annoying ... AutoSuggest just shows you things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm currently looking at this one: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/akautocomplete.aspx Will try to remember to post my findings.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to create it yourself, IMHO.  However if you google 'autosuggest textbox', you should find some examples on how to do it.

The examples might not be in in MFC though, but I'm sure they can help you along.

Comment: I think the term is "autocomplete".

Comment: I don't think so. Autocomplete means the suggestion is shown in the edit-box, autosuggest means a list of multiple suggestions is shown. But I guess the terms are interchangeable in real life.

Answer (score 1):

[This one](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/combocompletion.aspx) is a good start:

Comment: It's pretty good, but can you force the drop-down to automatically show when there are multiple suggestions? If I type "John" there could be 10 possible suggestions, and I'd like the drop-down to appear and show them.